# EF navigation properties are not loaded if they had default value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading, navigation-properties

I have a `Transaction` class in code-first approach with a navigation property `Account`.

```
public class Transaction 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public Transaction() 
    {
        // Account = new Account(GlobalValues.AppData.DefaultAccount); // this causes the problem!!!
    }
}
```

If in the default constructor of `Transaction` `Account` is not set, then

```
var toDisplay = db.Transactions.Take(10).ToList();
```

reads `Account` properly. If `Account` is set in the default constructor then it seems `Account` is not read, but the value set in the constructor is used. I tried eager loading but it did not help.

```
var toDisplay3 = db.Transactions.Take(10).Include(e => e.Account).ToList();
```

My current workaround is to set only `AccountId` in the constructor but it causes problem elsewhere.

Comment: So if there is no child data for account, then you want to use a default, else have it eagerly loaded form the DB?

Comment: @TheGeneral   Each `Transaction` has an `Account` in the DB. I always want to read them, but when the default constructor gives value to `Account` then the value in the DB is ignored.